# Get-ADComputer of a specific organizational unit in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Using the active directory module I need to Get-ADComputer of all the computers in an specific OU and list all their properties.

I tried something like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'DistinguishedName -like "*OU=Testing*"'
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to figure it out yourself?

Comment: @mjolinor I edited my question with what I tried.

Comment: And what was your result?

Comment: @mjolinor It returns nothing.

Comment: Sounds right. -eq means "is equal to", IOW an exact match.  "*OU=Testing*" is not a valid distinguished name, so it's not going to find one with that name.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for (and probably could have found on your own if you had done a simple `get-help get-adcomputer -detailed`) is the -SeachBase option for that command. Since you only want one specific OU you may want to use the -SearchScope option as well.

```
Get-ADComputer -searchbase "OU=Testing,CN=Some,CN=Domain,CN=Com" -SearchScope 0 -Filter *
```

Obviously you will need to change the path of the SearchBase to suite your needs.

Comment: For me, using PowerShell v4, the `-filter` option is still required. So `Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Testing,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Filter *` should work.

Comment: @Signal15 You are quite right, this was written years ago, and evidently I missed that when I wrote the answer. I'll update it to include that, thanks for catching it!